# How to specify offset using `@formula` and implement a similar function to `model.frame()` in R using Julia?

Tags: statistics, julia, linear-regression, glm

Given the model formula, response family and DataFrame, I would like to return as the output of this function things such as `n`, `p`, `model_matrix`, `model_response`, `model_offset`. Offsets are very important for our use case but I cannot work out how to specify a formula within Julia accounting for offset terms.

```
function frame(formula,family,data)
    # code to implement something similar to `model.frame` function in R

   return model_matrix,model_response,model_response
end
```